# Linking HUDLayer to GameplayLayer properly

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, layer, scene

I'm trying to pass the touch location from GameplayLayer to HUDLayer to see if user presses control buttons.

HudLayer.mm

```
-(void) handleTouchAtLocation:(CGPoint) location {
NSLog(@"Touch passed to HUD");
}
```

Gameplay.mm

```
enum {
   kHudLayer = 2;
};

+(CCScene *) scene {
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    HudLayer *hud = [HudLayer node];
    [scene addChild:hud z:kHudLayer];
    GameplayLayer *layer = [GameplayLayer node];
    [scene addChild:layer];
    return scene;
}

-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   for( UITouch *touch in touches ) {
      CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
      location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
      [self handTouchAtPoint:(location)];
   }
}

-(void) handleTouchAtPoint:(CGPoint)location {
   NSLog(@"Touch At Point");
   HudLayer *h1 = (HudLayer *)[self.parent getChildWithTag:kHudLayer];
   [h1 handleTouchAtLocation:location];
}
```

HudLayer.h is imported in GameplayLayer.h.
I'm getting the "Touch At Point" log but it's not going through to HUD layer for some reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only explanation is that `self.parent` has no child with the tag `kHudLayer`. If you set a breakpoint in handleTouchAtPoint you'll notice `h1` being nil after the `getChildWithTag` line did execute.

Comment: taking out .parent did the trick. I guess i got a little mixed up there. thanks

Comment: you seem to be using that constant as a zOrder, not a tag. So, if it now 'works', beware of future changes to the order in which you add objects to the parent.